# 2sxc - Adding "Entity" as Content Type. How to Filter by Type?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a setup where there is a relationship between 2 types of "App" data.

There is a data-type of "City" And a data-type of "Attraction".

1 City has many Attractions.

I am trying to add an "entity" type to "City" - So that you can add many "Attractions" to a city.

Because 2sxc is used quite a lot throughout the site, I'm trying to apply an initial filter to the "entity-type" so that the admin/end-user only sees Attraction entities.

I had previously installed the [REST Tutorial App](https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/tutorial-javascript-rest-api-using-jquery-and-angularjs) and it looks like the two data types associated with that app are showing up in the filter (See below).

**What do I need to do to get my own "data-types" into this dropdown field?**
[image: Diagram]

Comment: I'm unsure about what you're trying to do. Are you in the right app? Because if you don't see the types, you're probably on another app.

Comment: @iJungleBoy Hi Daniel - No I'm not in another app. Just doubled checked now... I thought I did everything right.

Comment: and your app has "Category" and "Feedback" as content-types? or is the screenshot from another app?

Comment: The screenshot is from my own app - But it's not pulling through the expected entities... I also have the REST tutorial App installed. And those entities (Category & feedback) are being pulled through into My App... The Category and feedback entities are showing up everywhere, but nothing else is...

Comment: For a quick workaround, just type in the name by klicking the bar-icon to the side of the dropdown. For the main problem, please open an issue on https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues